# Installing Xubuntu Bionic Beaver OCT 2022

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, security, lts

I am running an old Acer laptop from around 2006. I have 3GB of RAM with a dual-core Intel processor.

I was running Windows 7 up until a month ago, and I thought that I would switch to Linux to hopefully give the machine a new lease on life. I have tried both Lubuntu 22.04 and Xubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish).

I am sad to say the switch-over has been frustrating. The main problem that I am having is random freeze-ups of the system. I researched a little into this and some reported that hardware acceleration in Google Chrome was the cause. I disabled hardware acceleration and while the problem still occasionally happens, it is much less often. I was thinking that it might be related to the graphics card in the laptop, a GeForce 9300m GD.

I also find that the power savings settings appear to have no affect at all.

I would like to try an older release to see if this will play more nicely with my older machine. I had some security concerns at first, which is what have stopped me from doing this already. Today, though, I noticed that LTS distributions of Ubuntu have support for five years, and an additional five years with a subscription.

What I would like to know is: would it be wise to install either Lubuntu or Xubuntu 18.04.06 (Bionic Beaver) on my laptop?

Thanks very much for reading and for any help and advice.

Comment: The LTS is fine to go with, however, when they leave standard support, we no longer support them here.  Canonical themselves should support it but only for security updates is all.  Any bugs or problems will not be supported.  18.04 will leave standard support early next year in April.

Comment: Thank you Terrance for your quick reply. This is the answer I was hoping for. So it's okay to use until April. That suits me fine. I hope to be using a faster system by then. Thanks again!

Comment: Desktop releases of Ubuntu are only available for the *year.month* products; whilst many home users only consider the Ubuntu products they'd use, Ubuntu has reserved the *year* products (16, 18, 20 etc) for specialist server products, eg. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server (& Desktop) was released in April 2022, but Ubuntu Core 22 was released July 2022. Xubuntu, Lubuntu provide no support for the 18/20/22 products, only 18.04/20.04/22.04 & other *year.month* products.

Comment: Be aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu (such as Lubuntu, Xubuntu & all others) only have 3 years of support for LTS releases; thus the oldest supported is Lubuntu 20.04 LTS, Xubuntu 20.04 LTS etc.. For Lubuntu links are https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ and https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ (where you'll note the 3 years for all *flavors*).  The same applies to Xubuntu & other *flavors* too.. and if you look at [18.04.6 release annoucements](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) you'll note none are mentioned, nor any ISOs with those fixes.

Comment: I'll also provide a link to Lubuntu's discourse (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-18-04-lts-end-of-life-30-april-2021/2466/4) where I'll refer in that thread to using `ubuntu-support-status` to verify what parts of your system are still supported; that if your device is x86 32-bit only (*i386* in Debian/Ubuntu terms) you have no choice. If you use later releases, ensure you apply *swap* appropriately for your device (for some releases of Lubuntu you'll need to tweak the installed image on your box as per documentation!)   I've primarily used Lubuntu as example, links etc. apply to all

Comment: FYI:  No *flavor* packages get security fixes beyond the 3 years for LTS; so ESM/UA/Ubuntu-PRO will not provide additional security... Also as for what's supported with Ubuntu Desktop I'd recommend you look back at prior LTS releases that moved to ESM as examples... ie. yes it provides longer security; but it's only most of the packages on Ubuntu Desktop ISOs, with some *deb* packages only provided security fixes if converted to *snap* packages as per 16.04 for example..  ie. read the print (*it's not even small! but should be read regardless as you should never assume*)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that flavors of Ubuntu (such as Lubuntu, Xubuntu & all others) only have 3 years of support for LTS releases; thus the oldest supported is Lubuntu 20.04 LTS, Xubuntu 20.04 LTS etc.. For Lubuntu links are https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ and https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ (where you'll note the 3 years for all flavors). The same applies to Xubuntu & other flavors too.. and if you look at 18.04.6 release annoucements you'll note none are mentioned, nor any ISOs with those fixes.

> Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop,
> Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Base. All the remaining
> flavours will be supported for 3 years.

I'll also provide a link to Lubuntu's discourse (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-18-04-lts-end-of-life-30-april-2021/2466/4) where I'll refer in that thread to using `ubuntu-support-status` to verify what parts of your system are still supported; that if your device is x86 32-bit only (*i386* in Debian/Ubuntu terms) you have no choice. If you use later releases, ensure you apply *swap* appropriately for your device (for some releases of Lubuntu you'll need to tweak the installed image on your box as per documentation!)   I've primarily used Lubuntu as example, links etc. apply to all

No *flavor* packages get security fixes beyond the 3 years for LTS; so ESM/UA/Ubuntu-PRO will not provide additional security... Also as for what's supported with Ubuntu Desktop I'd recommend you look back at prior LTS releases that moved to ESM as examples... ie. yes it provides longer security; but it's only most of the packages on Ubuntu Desktop ISOs, with some *deb* packages only provided security fixes if converted to *snap* packages as per [16.04 for example](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/ESM/16.04)..  ie. read the print (*it's not even small! but should be read regardless as you should never assume*)

I perform QA-testing of Lubuntu releases up to current *kinetic* (*what will be Lubuntu 22.10 when released later this month*) and other *flavors* to including Xubuntu, with boxes as old as from 2005. An example includes

`lenovo thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb ram, i915)`

which is far from the oldest, but most have RAM expanded; that device has not. I used older devices up to 19.04 too, but those devices were *i386* or 32-bit x86 only, and were abandoned by Ubuntu after the *disco* (19.04) cycle (*meaning 18.04 or bionic is the last supported release if using one of those*).

With your limited RAM; ensure you chosen apps match the Desktop you'll use, ie. you want the desktop & apps to share resources, so you're not requiring multiple *libs* to co-exist in RAM wasting resources so you can use a DE(sktop) & apps that use different libraries/toolkits. Also ensure *swap* is set appropriately; this is very important for Lubuntu releases using the `calamares` installer, which has different defaults to *flavors* using `ubiquity` (Xubuntu uses `ubiquity`). The [Lubuntu discourse has pages](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/swap-and-lubuntu-faq/2591) on this, and the really help when RAM is limited (ie. less than 5GB)

*No flavor has support for Ubuntu specialist snap-only year products, ie. 16, 18, 20 & 22; desktops are provided only for the year.month products, ie. releases using the year.month format; 20.04 & 22.04 being the supported releases*

Also **note** Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last release of Lubuntu using the LXDE desktop, thus all upgrades will require re-install of later products (ie. *18.10 or later use LXQt & you risk breaking your system or a less than ideal experience if you don't clean install*).  This makes Lubuntu 18.04 LTS installs a less than ideal situation if you intend keeping the device for anything but a short period.

Comment: If you're wanting to use GTK+ apps/programs, I'd for sure recommend Xubuntu.  Lubuntu maybe *lighter* out of the box than Xubuntu, but few of us use the OS by itself & add apps, and Lubuntu uses LXQt uses Qt5, thus remains lightest when Qt5 apps are used, Xubuntu using GTK3 is *heavier* for sure, but if GTK3 apps are being used; it'll catch up & perform better than Lubuntu/LXQt.  I still use devices with only 1GB of RAM, but the less RAM you have, the more careful you need to be if performance matters to you. Personal taste (re: DE) is less important when you have limited RAM in my opinion.

Comment: As an aside (*that may mean something, may not*), I booted up the *thinkpad sl510* mentioned and my system currently is 20.04.5; in my preference for multiple DEs it contains both `xubuntu-desktop` & `lubuntu-desktop`. On that limited (RAM) device I didn't really want the *snap* packaged `firefox` which was a plus for keeping 20.04, it didn't have space to *release-upgrade* to 22.04 when I looked (*a case where I often upgrade via re-install; non-destructively*) but I've not done that yet. Maybe that's significant. Either way with our last 20.04.5 released, it won't return to 20.04 (again)

Comment: Thank you guiverc for all of the info! It seems there are many aspects of choosing the right distro and release to consider here. Thanks for the enlightening facts. I will follow up on some of your references. Possibly Xubuntu 22.04 may be the best choice for my older system for better performance while maintaining security, considering...
Thanks. I would up-vote your post, though I don't have enough points as of yet. I'll be revisiting this post though I'm sure.

Comment: guiverc, I was wondering also, I am about to install the Xubuntu 18.04 distro. The thing is that I will be using the system for some development tasks and also carrying out some business and financial activities... would you recommend this at all?

Are there some procedures I can follow to make Xubuntu 18 "safe" (or as safe as can be). Some reasonable system hardening to a level that would be on par of that of other users using the latest distros... it seems that if there is no longer security updates support, that this might be a silly question. Thanks guiverc.

Comment: 18 & 18.04 are different systems, Ubuntu's 16, 18, 20 & 22 all run the same user packages thus one is as safe as another; that is not the same as 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 & 22.04 which do not unless *snap* packages are used. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` again, sure you can watch upstream & later version security fixes, and backport them yourself (*that's more work than just using a later release*), or replace your apps with a different type of package that still gets updates (eg. *snap*).. I still use 18.04 as talked about in posts I've linked, but I use that install differently